# What is the correct method of design in a MVC project in regards to the model, view, and controller directories?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am in the starting stages of moving from NET c# to MVC, and am wondering about something. I see all of these examples and cases where the code is not organized in any manner within the three primary directories (Model, View, Controller). For example, is it bad practice to have my project design such as "root/Controller/Employee/[multiple controllers for employee, and then root/Controller/ProjectPhase/[multiple controllers for project phase objects], or is it assumed that this need should not be necessary according to the already efficient design implementation of the standard MVC project. Maybe I am overlooking/complicating this or prematurely asking this question, and should give it some more time and or reading/research, but was curios on the topic.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All controllers should be directly below controller folder.  If you want to segment your controllers, you need to use Areas.  With Areas you can have multiple trees of models views and controller.